# Why is there a white space between my button and its border?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, height, margins

#### Web app

[image: webapp]

#### snippet

[image: snippet]

I'm running into a problem with the height of a button in Chrome. It works in Firefox just fine, but it's not filling in the entire height though I have it set to 100%. It's not making much sense to me, so can someone please explain this to me?

It seems to work in the snippet? I'm 100% not using JavaScript to set any of this: purely the CSS I have listed below.

It wasn't a problem until today...which is super weird.

```css
body {
 background-color: dimgrey;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.topbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px lightgrey solid;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: calc(80%-1px);
  height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}
.login-button {
  max-width: 15%;
  min-width: 15%;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px lightgrey solid;
  login_text: 'color';
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
.e-mess {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='topbar'>
  <div class='e-mess'></div>
  <button class='login-button'>login</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it's the border bottom of the topbar

Comment: yeah, but it works in the snippet if you run it

Comment: it shouldn't be white...it's lightgrey as listed in the css

Comment: so there is more CSS involved

Comment: nope...not for the top bar...that's literally all of it...minus some text color styling http://dev.orderonlinellc.com/ there's the app if you wanna play with it...it's super irritating...it's like off by `.5px` which doesn't make sense -_-

Comment: I think I might have fixed it....looks like I'm going to have to set all of the values for height and not just that single value for the `topbar` class? ughghghghg lol
`max-height: 60px;
    min-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this was the issue, but I had to set the `min-height` property for the `topbar` class.

```css
.topbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px lightgrey solid;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: calc(80%-1px);
  min-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: You should remove the login-text:'color' from the css, as this is causing an error in your css (because there's no native css property called login_text) Also try and avoid using color names, use the hex codes instead (dimgrey is supposed to be #696969 or Dimgray (with an a). The empty div html  over the login button was probably creating a space, you could've worked around it by using a margin-bottom of -1, but better css on the whole is advised..